# Is there a word for the glow one emanates when beaming with happiness?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a singular word in the English language that can be defined as "The glow one emanates when beaming with happiness?" If not, any suggestions?

Comment: Not a single word, but: "aura of happiness"?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps "**radiance**" comes close to a glowing display of happiness - for example as an adjective - They all displayed *radiant smiles*.

> Her **radiance** displayed her emotional response to the good news.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/radiance